# Importing CSV to SQL-Server - Performance

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, csv

I created a small project, which allows the user to import a CSV-File into SQL via Entity-Framework. The main procedure is looking like this:

```
using (TextFieldParser tx = new TextFieldParser(file, Encoding.UTF8))
        { 
            tx.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            tx.SetDelimiters(";");
            tx.ReadLine(); //The First Line are the headers, no need

            while (!tx.EndOfData)
            {
                decimal decTmp;
                int intTmp;

                string[] fields = tx.ReadFields();

                //Convert every field to the appropriate type, tryparse if nullable
                ReportInfo("Verarbeite Nummer: " + fields[(int)ConnectionEvaluationFileField.PhoneNumber].Trim());

                Verbindunganalyse con = new Verbindunganalyse();
                con.Auswertungszeitraum = fields[(int)ConnectionEvaluationFileField.EvaluationTimeSpan].TrimStart('0');
                con.Betrag_inkl_MWST_CHF = Decimal.Parse(fields[(int)ConnectionEvaluationFileField.Cost]);
                if (decimal.TryParse(fields[(int)ConnectionEvaluationFileField.DataInMb], out decTmp))
                    con.Daten_MB = decTmp;
                con.Durchwahlnummer = Int64.Parse(fields[(int)ConnectionEvaluationFileField.PhoneNumber]);
                con.Produkteigenschaft = fields[(int)ConnectionEvaluationFileField.ProductProperty];
                if (Int32.TryParse(fields[(int)ConnectionEvaluationFileField.Messages], out intTmp))
                    con.SMS_MMS_Anzahl = intTmp;
                con.TelefonieDauer = TimeSpan.Parse(fields[(int)ConnectionEvaluationFileField.CallLength]);

                con.Untergruppe = fields[(int)ConnectionEvaluationFileField.SubGroup];

                if (Int32.TryParse(fields[(int)ConnectionEvaluationFileField.Connections], out intTmp))
                    con.Verbindungen_Anzahl = intTmp;

                container.Verbindunganalyse.Add(con);
            }
        }
```

It's german, but I think the code is quite clear: I read the Data with the TextFieldParser, create a new Entitiy and parse/Check the fields into the property.

The problem: The customer used to have a Access-Solution, which needed like 20-30 Seconds to import the Data, with my solution, I need like 2-3 Minutes for 2 Files a 5k Datasets.

I found some BulkInsert like https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/ ,but we're speaking here about like 10k Datasets in both files together.

I removed the ReportInfo etc., but I can't see a way making this work faster. Do you see a possibility to make such stuff faster with EF? Or is the TextFieldParser just very slow and I need to check there?

Comment: Do you know which part is slow? Is it the loop through the text file? Is it the insert into Entity Framework? If it is the latter then you might be better using BulkInsert and by-passing EntityFramework.

Comment: Well no Dataset needs longer than some Milliseconds, the problem is, Access can Bulk insert into SQL with ease. The quest is to fight that. It can be slower, but not just by a factor of 10

Comment: Bulk insert works quite efficiently in SQL Server:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx.

Comment: Try setting these flags on your context `Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false` and `Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false`.  Alternatively you could use `SqlBulkCopy` instead of EF to insert the data.

Comment: Well, I would guess that Access and SQL Server will work well together and behind the scenes are using SQL. You won't be able to beat that performance. If you put a timer (System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch) on the While loop and comment out the EF stuff, what results do you get?

Comment: Since I'm using EF, I will give the EFBulkInsert then a try

Comment: ZerO, your idea Configs werea huge help, which made the program running from 2-3 Minutes to 30-40 Seconds. If you write it as answer I'd say this is a answer and a very good Step

Comment: Try with table valued parameters. you can basicaly do like this
Insert into table (col1,col2,col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3 from @parameter

Read more about it here: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I have been experimenting with this myself. I tried both the [Entity Framework Seeder NuGet package](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2014/06/02/introduction-entity-framework-seeder.aspx) and a [bare-metal SQL bulk insert](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/) with the following code;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempTable] (
    [Field] type constraints,
    etc...
)
GO
BULK INSERT TempTable FROM 'filePath' WITH (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
)
GO
INSERT INTO [FinalTable] SELECT [Fields] FROM [TempTable]
GO
DROP TABLE [TempTable]
```

The seeder method inserts 10,000 records in 67 seconds and the bulk insert method takes 223 ms. It's a no-brainer really.